# I want to convert a vector mask in to a layer mask without my image dissapearing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I initially had a vector mask, which I then realise that I needed to fade some stuff out, but it didn't work in a vector mask. I then converted the vector mask into a layer mask which it rasterised, but my image disappeared.

Is there any way to convert it without it changing anything?
If not, is there an easy way to fade stuff out in a vector mask?

PLS help.

Answer (score 0):

Here the original image contains a black, a red and a blue dot. The vector mask covers only the black and the red, so the blue one is invisible:

[image]

The blue dot can still be seen in the layer icon.

Select the vector mask path and draw a new path in subtract mode to reduce the area of the existing vector mask:

[image]

[image]

The just drawn rectangle covers the red circle, so it becomes invisible.

The original vector mask and the new rectangle stay still as independent subpaths. Drawing a new curve inserts a subpath to the selected path. The subtraction doesn't change drawn curves, it's used as the rule how the new subpath is taken into the account when the image with masks is rendered. I admit somehow simpler behaviour would be less confusing. But that's how it's programmed.

It can also be useful. In the next image the new rectangle is selected with the path selection tool. It must be selected from the image, subpaths cannot be accessed separately in the Paths panel. The mode is changed to "Add" and the rectangle is moved rightwards so that the blue dot is partially covered:

[image]

If you want to convert the vector mask to a layer mask, simply right click the vector mask icon in the layers panel and select "Rasterize vector mask". The result in my case is this:

[image]

Nothing of the layer content vanished. Disabling the layer mask shows that everything is still there:

[image]

BTW. I use a legacy version of Photoshop.